# Camera.getPicture is not a function in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, camera

I am using camera plugin to click picture in ionic app, but i am getting the following error

```
OrdercancelPage.html:24 ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at Camera.getPicture (index.js:125)
at OrdercancelPage.webpackJsonp.444.OrdercancelPage.getphoto (ordercancel.ts:24)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (OrdercancelPage.html:24)
at handleEvent (core.js:13547)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14643)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:9962)
at core.js:10587
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2628)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
```

My code is

```
getphoto(){
this.camera.getPicture({
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  targetWidth: 1024,
  targetHeight: 720
}).then((imageData) => {
  // imageData is a base64 encoded string
  this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

}

I am using the plugin

```
import {   Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
```

Comment: same on my end
If you manage to solve it please tell me your solution

Comment: Remove Camera plugin First and then Do 1) ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera 2) npm install @ionic-native/camera@4.20.0

Comment: Hope you added it in provider array in app.module.ts

Comment: Did you properly install Camera plugin? Did you follow the docs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just remove your plugin and install-

```
npm install @ionic-native/camera@4.20.0
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: I am getting error in ionic3 after taking picture with camera `Error capturing image.`. Any solution for that ? It works fine with gallery selection.

Answer (score 6):

The problem was that , i was using plugin version 5.0.0 . I downgraded to version 4.x.x using package.json and it worked fine without using ngx to import.